# Generated Zip file is invalid after downloading from S3

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-sdk

I am creating a zip file that, appears, valid but is always invalid after I have put it to a Amazon S3 bucket. I am using System.IO.Compression for the task and AmazonS3Client for uploading:

```
private byte[] GenerateZipFile(string tenant)
{
   byte[] zipData;

   var results = QueryAggregateTable(tenant);
   using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
   {
      foreach (var item in results)
      {
          var archiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry($"{item.RowKey:D3}.json", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
          using (var entryStream = archiveEntry.Open())
          {
              var entryBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item.Data);
              entryStream.Write(entryBytes, 0, item.Data.Length);
          }
      }

      zipData = memoryStream.ToArray();
   }

   return zipData;
}
```

and

```
private async Task UploadToAmazon(byte[] zipData, string tenant)
{
    var bucketName = _config["egestionBucketName"];
    var configCreds = _config["egestionAwsCredentials"].Split(":");

    var awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(configCreds[0], configCreds[1]);
    var awsRegion = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(_config["egestionRegionEndpointSystemName"]);

    var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreds, awsRegion);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(zipData))
    {
        var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = $"{tenant}-{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s")}.zip",
            InputStream = stream,
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.BucketOwnerFullControl
        };

        await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);
    }
```

}

The byte array looks good after returning from generation and the upload method does, in fact, load a file with the correct name to the bucket. When I attempt to download the file to check it I cannot open it with a message stating it is invalid.

I have had some problems with async/await and suspect it may be something related but there is no non async option for PutObject that I can find. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an async-await issue.

The bytes from the memory stream are being collected before the archive has had a chance to write all the data to the stream. The uploaded archive is incomplete and therefore invalid when downloaded.

Move

```
zipData = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

to outside of the archive `using` block so that any buffered data is flushed to the backing stream when the archive is disposed.

```
//...

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true)) {
        foreach (var item in results) {
            var archiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry($"{item.RowKey:D3}.json", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
            using (var entryStream = archiveEntry.Open()) {
                var entryBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item.Data);
                entryStream.Write(entryBytes, 0, entryBytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }//Archive disposed and pushed any remaining buffered data to the stream.
    zipData = memoryStream.ToArray();
}

//...
```

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi but I thought that part was ok as I had data in the zipData variable. I have made the change anyway but I still have the same outcome.

Comment: Yes you would have data in the zipData, but not all the data. Hence invalid zip file. 
 Review the provided code again.

Comment: I apologise I had made some other changes and they must have been the issue then as I now have a working upload. \0/. Thank you @Nkosi